# Is it possible to use multiple resource bundles for a single jrxml report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am generating PDF report using Jasper. In jrxml file, I can read single property file as a resource bundle, but here I need to read 2 properties file to generate report as a BiLingual (two languages labels, one is in English and other is in Local language) report. Is sit possible in JasperReport to use multiple properties file. Or is there any other way around to do this?

Comment: No. You should use one file.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to have a single resource bundle is that it encapsulates all the text for one language. When the report is run, the report's locale (country and language) are provided. This causes the report to select the resource bundle for a particular language. Since the report template references the bundle keys, not their values, the generated report is output in a particular language.

If the report is meant to be bilingual (an unusual requirement because it's trivial to pass a Locale object into the report to generate a single language, which increases available page real-estate), create a resource bundle as normal, but update the labels to include both languages. This might resemble:

```
header.label.greeting = Hello / Bonjour
footer.label.page = Page / Page
body.label.name = Name / Nom
```

If English labels are always first, then simply default to using an English locale and name the resource bundle file accordingly.

This is flexible because it opens the possibility for more than bilingual resource bundles, such as separate English and French labels, should the requirements change in the future:

```
header.label.greeting = Hello
footer.label.page = Page
body.label.name = Name
```

---

```
header.label.greeting = Bonjour
footer.label.page = Page
body.label.name = Nom
```

If you were feeling particularly enthused, you could write a little bit of code to merge two resource bundles from different languages. That is, given the two sets of keys shown immediately above, you can produce a single resource bundle that combines each label using a slash.

For this approach to work, you'd have to have a convention that allows the merging code to distinguish between bilingual labels and non-bilingual labels, should any exist.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I solved the problem by setting English language as default Resource Bundle and passing local Resource Bundle as a parameter to jrxml file. In <textFieldExpression> tag, I am getting English labels using R{xyz} and local labels by using `$P{localized}.getString("xyz")` . Advantage of this is I can use any separator wherever I want.

Comment: If possible, avoid mixing how labels are retrieved by using `$R{...}` exclusively, rather than `$R{...}` and `$P{...}`. All report labels should be served from the same resource bundle.